# laravel 5.1 how this starter project route to /auth/login

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

i'm learning laravel, i've found a starter project here

https://github.com/mrakodol/Laravel-5-Bootstrap-3-Starter-Site

i'm wondering how the program set /auth/login to use login.blade.php, i see the route use these two lines:

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

The main question is i didn't find any part of the code will make the controller adapt the login.blade.php. how the program display the login form via /auth/login ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

This type of `route` definition is called implicit controllers.

The above `route` is same as

```
Route::controller('auth', 'Auth\AuthController');
Route::controller('password', 'Auth\PasswordController);
```

So, the `URI` will be `example.com/auth`.

The controller method accepts two arguments. The first is the base `URI` the controller handles, while the second is the class name of the controller.

Now, in the controller, the method names should begin with the HTTP verb they respond to followed by the title case version of the URI.

eg:

```
public function getLogin()
{
    //
}
```

This method will be responsible for the display (`GET`) of the page `example.com/auth/login`.

eg:

```
public function postLogin()
{
  //
}
```

This method will be responsible for the `POST` request from the `URI` `example.com/auth/login`.

If you take a look at the `Auth\AuthController`, you can see it uses `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php` class. Now if you navigate to that class, you can see another use `AuthenticatesUsers` class. If you inspect this class, you can see all the methods responsible for the `login` and related functions.

Similarly for the `PasswordController`.

Read more about the implicit controllers here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#implicit-controllers

Comment: i found vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php, if i need change the blade template, i need to edit this file?